# c++ delete should do nothing

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

Question:

is there any way to make delete behave like a dummy i.e do nothing when called?

Why I need the answer:

I'm using a custom memory pool that frees the all the object from memory when a static method is called `Pool::freeAllObjects()`.

all the classes have an overloaded operator new like the following:

```
void * operator new (size_t size)
{
void * obj = Pool::memory()->allocate(size);
Pool::memory()->save_destructor((ClassName*)obj);
return obj;
}
```

`Pool::memory()->save_destructor()` just saves a pointer to function that runs the destructor of a generic type.

if no one calls `delete` on the objects that are created with the pool then everything behaves correctly but in the code we want to use it there are many instances of objects which have `delete` called on, so for backward compatibility I tried to make an overloaded `delete` like this

```
void operator delete(void*) {/*do nothing*/}
```

in the classes that have the overloaded `new` using the `Pool::memory()`
, but it looks like that did not solve the problem. I used a simple std::cout to see the cons/destructor called and an overloaded delete like:

```
void operator delete(void*) {std::cout << "deleting ClassName" << std::endl;}
```

so in a code like this:

```
ClassName * instance = new ClassName();
instance->runMethod();
delete instance; //this is legacy code calling delete before the pool was developed
/*
 other code goes here
*/
Pool::freeAllObjects(); // oops instance was already deleted
```

I get the following output:

`constructing ClassName` <-- constructor called

`destructing ClassName` <-- destructor called because of calling delete

`deleting ClassName` <-- delete displaying its message

`destructing ClassName` <-- destructor called because of the Pool::freeAllObjects running the destructor on the object

EDIT:
sorry that I didn't mention that the requirement was not to use smart pointers and making operator delete private (which I think is the best option by the way) is also not allowed.

Comment: You can't stop the destructor from being called when delete is used. You can modify `operator delete`, but delete is a 2 step process: call the object's destructor then call `operator delete`. You could use `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` with a custom deleter which does not actually call delete though, and never deal with raw pointers or calling delete explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent `delete` from calling the destructor; that's
what it does.  But since you're catching the `operator delete`
function which is called later, you can use some sort of hidden
flag.  Something like:

```
union MemoryHeader
{
    bool hasBeenDeleted;
    double forAlignment;
};

void* operator new ( size_t size )
{
    MemoryHeader* hdr = static_cast<MemoryHeader*>(
                Pool::memory()->allocate( size + sizeof( MemoryHeader ) ) );
    hdr->hasBeenDeleted = false;
    void* obj = hdr + 1;
    Pool::memory()->save_destructor( (ClassName*)hdr );
    return obj;
}

void operator delete( void* obj )
{
    MemoryHeader* hdr = static_cast<MemoryHeader*>( obj ) - 1;
    hdr->hasBeenDeleted = true;
}
```

Then, when you run your deleters, you can check the flag.

Or perhaps even better, in your case; in your `operator delete`
function, just deregister the destructor for the object:  add
a `clear_destructor` function to what `Pool::memory()` returns,
and call it.

Comment: why are you adding +1 to hdr on `void* obj = hdr + 1;` and then subtracting it on delete, why not just `void* obj = hdr;` instead?

Comment: To account for the space used by MemoryHeader.

Comment: @jhoffman0x why adding +1 and not +2, +3 or something else? why is this needed? what happens if the +1/-1 are removed?

Comment: The +1/-1 offsets by the size of the MemoryHeader because they're being added to a MemoryHeader* and that's how pointer arithmetic works. In the case of +1 he has a MemoryHeader* and he wants to get the address of the object. In the case of -1 he has the address of the object and he wants to get the MemoryHeader*.

Comment: This is assuming that you have a MemoryHeader before every block of memory that you allocate for an object.

Comment: @jhoffman0x when I overloaded new/delete like the answer suggests I got "invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000078fb60 " and the app crashes,after I removed the +1/-1 the program worked smouthly

Comment: @exTrace101 I forgot to increase the size of the allocation to compensate for the extra memory used for the flag.  I've fixed that.  But there may be other errors; I've not actually tested it.  All I can say is that I've successfully used similar techniques in the past.

Comment: @exTrace101 Why?  I only have one hidden header, not 2.

Comment: @JamesKanze sorry I meant `void* obj = hdr + 1;` should be `void* obj = hdr;` that +1 is unneccecary

Comment: @JamesKanze why have you chosen a `double` instead of `int` for Alignment?

Comment: @exTrace101 Because that's what most systems require.  In actual production code, I'd use something more complex, and possibly implementation dependent.  (With C++11, I'd probably use the attribute `alignas( std::max_align_t )`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze the `void* obj = hdr + 1;` cause segmentation fault, as I updated the code to `void* obj = hdr;` the segmentation faults are gone.

Comment: @exTrace101 But the object constructed will overwrite your flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54111/discussion-between-extrace101-and-james-kanze).

Answer (score 1):

`operator delete` is a *deallocation function*.

A *delete expression* calls the destructor first, then the relevant deallocation function.

"Pool::memory()->save_destructor() just saves a pointer to function that runs the destructor of a generic type." is ungood design. Instead, if deallocation responsibility is to be shared, then handle that at a higher level by using **`std::shared_ptr`** (you can restrict your classes to only be instantiable via a function that produces a `std::shared_ptr`). That's what `std::shared_ptr` is for.

With the allocator responsible for destroying objects, high and low level concerns are conflated, which results in complexity and probably bugs.

With those concerns separated, e.g. by using `std::shared_ptr`, you get a simpler and more reliable design, which also will be more in line with such separation in the C++ language.

---

The classic book “Modern C++ Design” by Andrei Alexandrescu discusses in detail how to implement a custom allocation scheme. Chances are that you can find that allocator in the Loki library. I believe that it's open source.

---

If you want a Java-like automatic garbage collection then you might be able to use the Boehm collector. I know some folks have used it successfully on medium to large projects. However, I have no direct experience, but check it out if that's what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid destructor being called automatically you'd have to implement `placement new` operator, in case of which destructor must be called explicitly ( refer to [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html) ).

If you want to disable freeing memory by `delete` statement, overloading it is a good idea, either globally (if you know what you're doing) or per-class (use inheritance maybe. `new`/`delete` operators are inherited).

It all depends on what you want to achieve and what compatibility to existing system you must sustain.

Either way - it's do-able. Other question is - is that the way it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative you might consider is to disable use of `delete` for the relevant classes.

Simply make the destructor `protected` or `private`, and add the pool allocator as `friend`.

This *enforces the existing design*, instead of either *supporting incorrect use* (one other answer) by adding more complexity, or *changing the design* to something more simple and clean (my other answer).

Comment: This is really probably what he should do.  For his system to work, 1) the destructors have to be such that they don't have to be called immediately (no RAII, for example), and 2) he needs to somehow be able to call them when the memory actually is freed.  For the latter to work, he almost certainly needs all of his classes to derive from a common base.  So the real solution is to define the `operator new` and `operator delete` in that base; third party libraries which don't know anything about his classes will continue to work normally.