# C++ can change the call order of destructors can be harmful?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

I'm fiddling with a c++ pool allocator that destroys all objects in it when it's `Pool::releaseAllObjects()` method is called at the end of `main()`. but the Pool is destroying the objects in random order if somebody unexpectedly called delete on an object.
my question is how this random call order of the destructors at the end of `main()` can be "harmful"?

Comment: If the destructors are all correctly written it can't possibly be a problem.

Comment: @EJP can you please elaborate on how destructors can be written correctly and incorrectly? i.e what makes a destructors incorrectly written?

Comment: Destructors should not be dependent on life of other objects. Destruction is usually in reverse order of construction.

Comment: `if somebody unexpectedly called delete on an object`? If I understand this correctly, this would mean that an object is deleted twice, once by the user and once by the pool allocator. This is undefined behaviour and should never happen.

Comment: @anderas we found a solution to that problem see [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744531/c-delete-should-do-nothing)

Comment: Well, that "solution" there is part of the problem I think. Usually you have a few top-level objects which own their (physical and logical) subobjects. C++ semantics assure that the constructors and destructors run in the right order, even if exceptions are thrown etc. But since you're fiddling with that order, you become **fully** responsible. IOW, if you don't understand the scope of responsibilities, you probably shouldn't try to change this order.

Answer (score 0):

The order does not matter as long as it does not matter to the constructor bodies. If the objects refer to each other, and call methods on the referee in the destructor, than the order of destruction obviously matters. Otherwise you are safe.